# Using JavaFX to load google map html

Tags: javascript, java, javafx, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to load the javascript html file with javaFX.
The polylines in the html is working fine. But after loading with javaFX, the polylines is moving\breaking into multiple line if I try to zoom in and out.

java code

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import java.net.URL;

public class GoogleApp extends Application {


    private Scene scene;
    MyBrowser myBrowser;
    double lat;
    double lon;
    private Stage stage;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        this.stage = stage;


        myBrowser = new MyBrowser();
        Scene scene = new Scene(myBrowser);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }



    class MyBrowser extends Pane {


        WebView webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine webEngine = webView.getEngine();


        public MyBrowser() {


            final URL urlGoogleMaps = getClass().getResource("demo2.html");
            webEngine.load(urlGoogleMaps.toExternalForm());

            getChildren().add(webView);

        }
    }
}
```

javacript html code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Simple Polylines</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

      // This example creates a 2-pixel-wide red polyline showing the path of
      // the first trans-Pacific flight between Oakland, CA, and Brisbane,
      // Australia which was made by Charles Kingsford Smith.

      function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 3,
          center: {lat: 0, lng: -180},
          mapTypeId: 'terrain'
        });

        var flightPlanCoordinates = [
          {lat: 37.772, lng: -122.214},
          {lat: 21.291, lng: -157.821},
          {lat: -18.142, lng: 178.431},
          {lat: -27.467, lng: 153.027}
        ];
        var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
          path: flightPlanCoordinates,
          geodesic: true,
          strokeColor: '#FF0000',
          strokeOpacity: 1.0,
          strokeWeight: 2
        });

        flightPath.setMap(map);
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

before loading

[image: javascript html file]

loading with javaFX

[image: load by java]

Comment: Did you try [GMapsFX](https://rterp.github.io/GMapsFX/)?